# ms sql server vs ms sql compact

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have to use ms sql database in my ASP.NET project and
I want to use a local database file without installing sql server. 
Do I have to use mdf file or I should do it with ms sql compact?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are a number of differences between SQL Server and SQL Compact in terms of the operations they support, data types etc. SQL Compact might work for you depending on your requirements but transitioning to full-blown SQL Server later might change your applications landscape a bit. What's your reasons for not wanting to install SQL Server, is it the license cost? If so, Express edition is free to download and use and suitable for development work, and supports a comprehensive subset of the features of the enterprise-level versions of SQL Server.

Comment: If you don't want to install Sql Server you should use Sql Server Compact Edition (or if you need stored procedures and triggers LocalDB)

Answer (score 1):

Use may want to use LocalDb. Compact is old way of doing it.

Or try this post . it will give you an idea.
[Add *.mdf file to C# Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821864/add-mdf-file-to-c-sharp-project)