# Packaging C# Software project which used .mdf database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have developed a c# software project which used MSSQL **.mdf** database. Actually at development time I connected my application logic from the SQL Server Administrator.

**My Specific Question is:**

How can I deploy the application on to another computer without installing the SQL Server management Studio, just access the .mdf database only?

The current development connection string is:

```
<add name="LocalString" connectionString="server=(local); Database=MYDB; user id=xxx;password=xxxxx"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Note that I am using **App.Config** connection string for entire system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add \*.mdf file to C# Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821864/add-mdf-file-to-c-sharp-project)

Comment: [I don't think it is possible to interact with an MDF file without going through a SQL Server engine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10366632/3796048) will help you

Comment: I don't think it's possibile to interact with a mdf-database without a sql-server engine. For SQL Server 2012 you can download the SqlLocalDb runtime.